# "Breakpoint" which stops whereever a property is changed

Tags: javascript, extjs

I can access a certain property and log its value to console:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("Entry")[0].down('combobox[name=User]').value;
```

When I do this before submitting the form that the combo is part of, the value is `["testuser"]`, but after form submission success, the value is `["testuser",""]`, so it has changed in the meantime. I cannot reproduce this behaviour in a fiddle.

So I have tried to debug by searching for all instances where the `value` property is set, and add console logging to every I found, but none of them are reached.

**Can I use a browser console or FireBug or similar plugin to find out when and where the property is changed? Is there some "conditional breakpoint" that stops execution when and where a certain property is changed?**

Comment: None of the possibilities outlined in the original question work for an array. It seems as if the empty string is pushed or merged or somehow else injected into value, the value seems not to be set via a setter.

Comment: I temporarily overrode the `push` function like this: `Ext.ComponentQuery.query("Entry")[0].down('combobox[name=User]').value.push=function() {console.log(arguments.caller.callee)};` and found that I somewhere did `var x = getValue(); x.push(someVal)`. I think in earlier versions (4.2.x) getValue returned a new value every time, but in 6.0.x, it doesn't.